# how to get description of error in unix

Tags: unix, sh

Hello Friend I have a unix script, which moves files from one folder to another folder with changed name. File size is very large.

I have put the echo "Return code :" $0 to get the result code of file mv command. This will return either 1 or 0.
I am getting 1 for particular file, which is very large. Can you suggest how do i get the description of the error?
Thanks
Deepak

Comment: `$0` is the name of the script; I think you mean `$?`. Please include the exact command your script is actually using in the question. If `mv` fails, it will set `$?` to `1` *and* print an error message to stderr.

Answer (score 2):

Try `mv -v` to make `mv` verbose about what it is doing.

Comment: I believe all that does is print the name of each file before moving it. This is unlikely to yield any information the OP doesn't already have.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting information about what `mv` is doing is, as long as you are using Linux, to use the `strace` command, along with the command you want to trace, as this:

```
strace mv file1 file2
```

This will give you information about any and all system calls issued by `mv`, their parameters and their results. Invaluable tool to trace programs searching for unexpected errors while dealing with the OS.

Comment: This is more of a debugging tip than something you would want to include in a script.

Comment: Looking at the error message `mv` will print to stderr is a lot simpler (the OP does not appear to have done that).